# Convexity of a subset of $R^3$ based on its bounding surface

Tags: convex-analysis, surfaces

Let D be a closed region in $R^3$ whose boundary S is a closed, smooth, orientable surface. The tangent plane at every point on S intersects it in a connected set $M$. Is D (the interior of S) a convex set?

This statement seems intuitively plausible to me. If it is not true, a counterexample would be welcome. If false, "technical" modifications to the statement that make it true would also be most helpful.

Also, if true, to what extent can the smoothness restriction be weakened / generalized?

Thanks.

Comment: how do you define exactly a region? I can imagine that the unit sphere is not a region (if yes, then it is a counter-example).

Comment: Anyway you should have a look at the Supporting Hyperplane theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supporting_hyperplane